# Link Sprint Capacity with Outlook Calandar

Tags: outlook, azure-devops, capacity, sprint

I’m not sure if this question is for StackOverflow or some other Q&A site.
Under the Capacity tab we have to manually update for each team member's annual leave that have been booked. Is it possible to link this to the outlook calendar?

[image]

**Edit**: Since its put on hold due to not being specific, I have edited it just to link the **Capacity** tab with the **outlook calendar**. Basically, the idea is to not manually update the capacity for each employee for the dates sprint is being planned. Hope this will help and encourage others to attempt the answer.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  My team tends to get roped into a lot of meetings during the course of a sprint (during which we are not working the project).  I'd like to see capacity changes based on the number of meetings that get scheduled.  Capacity at the start of the sprint was 30, but by the end actual capacity was 20.